# How can I include shaded POM of a library/sdk in my application's pom.xml?

Tags: java, maven, sdk, pom.xml, fatjar

I have a library/sdk in which I created a shaded pom `java-sdk-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.pom` using maven shade plugin .
which contains all jars and classes which are used as dependencies . Now I want to integrate this in my sample application so that I can use it as an external library.
I have copied it to my applications target folder and tried to run `mvn clean install`.
But its not working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I made a seperated module where I used all other modules as dependency .
After this I exported this to my client app where I was able to access all other modules also as they were compiled in a single jar file .

PS: I was able to do it without using fat Jar ;)